# How can I pass the data back to index file?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have an index.php file to contain the layout of my website. In the index file, I have a search form  which sends data to another php file to process(action="search.php"). My problem is: I can select the data that suits the user's keyword and output it, but the output isn't with the layout, it's just text on white background. What I need to know is: How can I pass the data that I've selected back to index.php so that it can have layout? I've tried window.location and include but it didn't work. Here's my code:

```
<?php
$search=$_GET['search'];// name of the text field is "search"
include('connectdb.php');
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM article WHERE header LIKE '%".$search."%'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{?>        
 <?php   echo $row['header'];
echo $row['content'];
}
   ?>
```

Comment: In index file, I have a div called "content" where I used php to retrieve the data from the database and put into it. So what I mean is how can I put the searching result into that div.

Comment: you just create the same layout as `index.php` on the `search.php` page. say you have `<div class="main_content">blah blah</div>` on `index.php` then you just do the same thing on `search.php` `<div class="main_content">while($row = $mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo //whatever}` or if you want to do the search on the same page you can do it like, `<form action="" method="get"></form>`

Comment: here's the code in my content div:
<?php
$content=$_GET['mod'];
if($content=="") $content="home";
include("modules/".$content.".php");
?>
every link in the menubar is like this <a href='index.php?mod=videos'>Video</a>
so i when i put the search.php into the content div, the browser will show the home AND the search result

Answer (score 0):

Use php Header function to go back to index.php. This is a demo only. You just get the idea and design what you want.

```
<?php
$search=$_GET['search'];// name of the text field is "search"
include('connectdb.php');
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM article WHERE header LIKE '%".$search."%'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{?>        

header("index.php?header=".$row['header']."&content=".$row['content']);
}
?>
```

Then catch these details in your index file

```
<?php
$header=$_GET['header'];
$content=$_GET['content'];
?>
```

Comment: Sajitha: I've tried your solution but the result is a blank page

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this:

```
var text = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
        url: "search.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {search: text},
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(data){
        if(data){
        //here you are parsing json object
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        //0: Object
    //header: "blablabla"
    //content: "blablabla"
   //1: Object
        //header: "wwwwwws"
        //content: "wewesssss"
        //length will be equal of results amount
        var length = data.length;
        var li = '';
        //here you are making li
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
        li += '<li>';
        li += data[i]['header'] . data[i]['content'];
        li += '</li>';
        }
        //appending element in dom
        $('ul').html(li);
        }
        }
        });
```

this ajax...

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$row = json_encode($row);
eco $row;
//this will return json object 
//[{"header":"blablabla","content":"blablabla"},{"header":"wwwwwws","content":"wewesssss"}]
```

this your php

Comment: Can you put some comment to the above code, I'm totally new to stackoverflow and ajax so that would help me alot. Thanks!

Comment: I've added some comments. but I'm not fluent English speaker sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example, you just gotta copy the exact same layout of index.php and implement it on search.php if you are selecting data from database on index.php then do the same query on search.php

style.css

```
.center_content{
 width:500px;
 height:300px;
 background:yellow;
 border:1px solid;
 }
 .right_column{
 width:200px;
 height:300px;
 background:Red;
 display:inline-block;
  }
  .right_column{
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  background:green;
  display:inline-block;
   }
```

index.php

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<form method="get" action="send.php">
<input type="text" name="search"  placeholder="search here">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<div class="left_column">blah blah</div>
<div class="center_content">
put whatever you want here
</div>
<div class="right_column">blah blah</div>
```

search.php

```
<form method="get" action="">
<input type="text" name="search"  placeholder="search here">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<div class="left_column">blah blah</div>
<div class="center_content">
 <?php
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
 $search=$_GET['search'];// name of the text field is "search"
include('connectdb.php');
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM article WHERE header LIKE '%".$search."%'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{?>        
 <?php   echo $row['header'];
echo $row['content'];
}}

 ?> 
</div>
<div class="right_column">blah blah</div>
```